# Updating Fragment ui after every interval of time using getActivity.runOnUiThread()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As i put my Title above , in my app i am using only one Activity but having lots of fragments that are changed according to Logic.
I need to Change every Fragment ui after some interval pf time and for that i am using

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {}
  });
```

but for no reason my app crashes after 24 hr running schedule.
and one more thing i am using this fragment multiple times in same activity with having 1X3 Template .
No crashlatics report Nothing.

Comment: Maybe you might be accessing views of wrong fragment,that cause trouble

Comment: No i am calling wright fragment data is shown as i assigned respectively

Comment: Can you add code to show show you are running something every interval? Also, seeing the kind of changes you are making would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i got the issue where i am lagging

Answer (score -2):

## Use

```
  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, "YOUR FRAGMENT").commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

## Instead of

```
  supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, "YOUR FRAGMENT").commitNow()
```